# Start of week number in an year - Snowflakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Week number of 2021 starts with 53. I would want it to be 1. Every year week number has to reset and start with 1.

Example below query returns 1 in sql

```
select datepart(week,'2021-01-01')
```

But select week('2021-01-01'::date) return 53 in Snowflakes. I need the result to be 1 in snowflakes.

Comment: *Week Number of 2021 starts with 53* That's not quite accurate - January 1st 2021 is, on the ISO calendar, in week 53 of year 2020.  ISO year 2021 week 1 begins on Monday 4th January.  I suggest you bend your thinking to the ISO calendar, trying to bend your software systems away from that will be laborious at best, at worst it will lead to despair possibly even madness.

Comment: If that select statement is SQL Server, you'll get 53 by using iso_week in datepart.

Answer (score 1):

alter session set week_of_year_policy=1;

Added this before my query in snowflakes and now week number starts with 1 for year 2021.

Comment: WEEK_START is another session parameter to consider when working with dates. You might consider WEEK_START=7 to provide 1-7 starting with Sunday. In another case of opinionated systems, SF likes ISO defaults, so the default here is 0, which defines Sundays = 0, thru Saturdays = 6.